# How to auto login a user in django if the tab was closed and he wasn't logged out?

Tags: python, django, authentication, backend

I am working on a Django project. I have a backened(Django) and frontend(HTML, CSS,JS).
Everything is working as expected like login, registration, logout, etc.
However, one requirement, and I know it's a very common one, is that if the tab is closed after user logs in(he didn't logout), and the user reopens the url of login, he should be taken to the dashboard instead of again asking for login credentials on login screen.

**What Have I tried?**

I saw some other answers and I tried putting this check in the "login/" url of my page:

```
request.user.is_authenticated
```

It always gives false if I place this check on the login page. I put it on login page's Get method because I want that if user was logged in and he tries to go to the login url, he gets redirected to dashboard. But it always gives False.

**What I want help with?**

It would be very kind if anyone can guide me on how to achieve the above objective.

Comment: Documentation suggests using session cookies (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use cookies.
For Example, you can create a cookie and set the value to true at every login.
This can be done as(views.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render  
from django.http import HttpResponse  
  
def setcookie(request):  
    response = HttpResponse("Cookie Set")  
    response.set_cookie('isloggedin', True)  
    return response  
def getcookie(request):  
    loggedin = request.COOKIES['isloggedin]  
    return HttpResponse("Login: " +  loggedin);
```

In my opinion, the best max_age would be a day.
Also make these changes in urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import path  
from myapp import views  
urlpatterns = [  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
    path('index/', views.index),  
    path('scookie',views.setcookie), #this
    path('gcookie',views.getcookie)  #and this
]
```

Reference: https://www.javatpoint.com/django-cookie

Comment: while this link may solve the problem, in case, this link is removed or not available in future this answer is not helpful, so please add a description to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde Thank You for telling me about that :)

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra thank you for the answer it was very helpful and helped me solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a token that you pass to frontend upon login, and it stored in the cookies. In your case if you get logged out after closing browser tab, that means you're not able to store the token in the browser.
As mentioned in a comment, try to use sessions or implement authentication system [Simple JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)